# Manual line break in tabular (tabu) breaks the layout of other columns if not using X column parameter

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabu

I know this problem has been discussed many times, and the proposed solutions were to use yet nested parboxes inside table cells, but I would like to avoid that. Up to now, I was using my table with each column defined with the `X` option. The newlines statements were taken into account and this was working nicely.
[image]

Then, I decided that the first column was a bit too large and I replaced the `X` column statement by `l` for the left column. However the result I got now is not properly aligned. As you see, I got unnecessary blank spaces and the newlines were discarded.

[image]

The minimal working code I have:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
% Add extra space for proper alignement between table rows
\tabulinesep = 3pt
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabu}{X X X}\toprule
        Catégories & Objectifs de la vue & Exemples de vue\\\midrule
        Contenu

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-a}} & Afficher un type particulier de contenu comme une image ou un texte & Image view, label\\

        Collections

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-b}} & Afficher des collections ou un groupe de vues & Collection view (conteneur), table view (ableau)\\

        Contrôles utilisateurs

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-c}} & Effectuer des actions pour afficher des éléments & Bouton, un slider (barre glissante), switch (interrupteur ON-OFF)\\

        Barres

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-a}} & Naviger dans les vues ou effectuer des actions & Barre d'outils, barre de navigation, barre d'onglets\\

        Entrées

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-b}} & Recevoir une entrée de l'utilisateur généralement à partir du clavier & Barre de recherche, text view\\

        Conteneurs

        \adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-c}} & Serveur de conteneurs pour d'autres vues & Simple vue, scroll view\\

        Modal & Interrompre le flux de l'application pour autoriser l'utilisateur à effectuer une action particulière & \enquote{Action sheet} (feuille d'actions), \enquote{alert view} (boites de dialogues d'avertissement)\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is by design. "l" columns is not in paragraph mode. Use a p{2cm} or something, but why not use tabu's advance and easy way to adjust column width in fraction of "X" {0.8X 1.1X 1.1X}? That is tabu's strength. Since I do not have your picture, it is to much work to provide you with a MWE. Basically, you change the column definition until it suits you: `\begin{tabu}{0.8X 1.1X 1.1X}\toprule`

Comment: @Sveinung Thanks. I wasn't aware of such a feature from tabu. After having read the documentation, the exact syntax seems to be `\begin{tabu}{X[0.8] X[1.1] X[1.1]}\toprule` but this has no effect on the problem I'm experiencing on the second and third columns. :-/

Comment: Try some of the tricks in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74928/9632

Comment: Or here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66942/9632  Your example is not compilable for anyone beside yourself, because we do not have access to the pictures.

Comment: `\\ ` ends the table row and starts the next row of the table, your red boxes just show the cells that are not in the short row.

Comment: If I try your example code I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment tabu undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \begin{tabu}
                {l X X}\toprule
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using manual carriage return/line feed to insert linebreaks for the images in the first column. Please replace them by `\newline` and do not use `\\` since your table environment will then consider you are trying to make a new row and the text in the second and third column will be shifted to the bottom, with a blank space added (see the space I marked in red in the following screenshot).

[image]

In the code this would give (example just of the first content row):

```
Contenu\newline\adjustbox{margin=1ex 0.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-a}} & Afficher un type particulier de contenu comme une image ou un texte & Image view, label\\
```

As @Sveinung clearly suggested in the comments of your question, this is due to the `l` parameter which doesn't defined columns in paragraph mode: `\newline` is not interpreted.

Fortunately, `tabu` does provide `X` columns with a coefficient (cf. point 2.3 [from the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf)). You basically just need to replace the line with `\begin{tabu}{X X X}\toprule` by `\begin{tabu}{X[0.8] X[1.1] X[1.1]}\toprule` for example.

This is now working like expected (notice how the first column has been resized but carriage returns have been kept):

[image]